# Does Sony PMW-EX1R HDMI output contain audio?

Tags: streaming, live, hdmi

I'm trying to get a Sony PMW-EX1R XDCAM to output HDMI for live streaming (using Teradek Vidiu). The picture looks fine, but it seems to lack audio. Is there a setting that I'm missing, or is it impossible to use HDMI in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDMI does support audio, but it is possible that either the PMW-EX1R doesn't output audio over HDMI (which would seem odd to me, but is possible).  It is also possible that the settings are wrong on the Vidiu.  The Vidiu appears to support audio input from either the HDMI port itself or a line input.  If it is expecting signal on the line input, it might ignore the HDMI audio.

I'd check the documentation for the Vidiu to see if you can find anything about that since I don't see anything in the PMW-EX1R documentation to answer it.  You could also try plugging the PMW-EX1R in to another HDMI device to see if you get audio.  If not, you can also try running the audio output of the camera in to the line input of the Vidiu and monitor off of the headphone jack of the Vidiu.

Comment: Oh. I feel so stupid, but of course there was a setting on the VidiU: Sound | Input, and it was set to Analogue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidHjelm - nothing stupid about it.  Mistakes like that happen all the time.  It seems simple once you know what it is, but there can be a pretty good number of variables to keep track of.  Best bet for a case like this is usually to follow and verify the signal path as much as possible, but that can be tough depending on what resources you have available at the time.